# How to fix docker container errors

Tags: docker

I have created docker image from my application written in C, however, after running image, I list to check if there is any container running but there is none. I checked my machine /var/logs/syslog and the output was as bellow. Any idea why the container is not running?

```
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore systemd-udevd[13471]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore systemd-udevd[13471]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth5b3e62c: No such file or directory
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore systemd-udevd[13472]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore systemd-udevd[13472]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vetha16701d: No such file or directory
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548522.9167] manager: (veth5b3e62c): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/33)
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.065424] docker0: port 1(vetha16701d) entered blocking state
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.065426] docker0: port 1(vetha16701d) entered disabled state
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.065480] device vetha16701d entered promiscuous mode
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.065545] docker0: port 1(vetha16701d) entered blocking state
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.065547] docker0: port 1(vetha16701d) entered forwarding state
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548522.9181] manager: (vetha16701d): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/34)
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.071998] docker0: port 1(vetha16701d) entered disabled state
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548522.9298] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vetha16701d, iface: vetha16701d)
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548522.9298] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vetha16701d, iface: vetha16701d): no ifupdown configuration found.
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548522.9300] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5b3e62c, iface: veth5b3e62c)
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548522.9301] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5b3e62c, iface: veth5b3e62c): no ifupdown configuration found.
May 15 16:15:22 cumucore containerd[1313]: time="2020-05-15T16:15:22.945456746+03:00" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/69402d9f19502efd82ac617dac339cdec3d2cabda5c16812c31791295924a9f3/shim.sock" debug=false pid=13487
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.265256] eth0: renamed from veth5b3e62c
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548523.1378] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5b3e62c, iface: veth5b3e62c)
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.288428] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vetha16701d: link becomes ready
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.288499] docker0: port 1(vetha16701d) entered blocking state
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.288500] docker0: port 1(vetha16701d) entered forwarding state
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548523.1442] device (vetha16701d): carrier: link connected
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548523.1443] device (docker0): carrier: link connected
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore gnome-shell[2823]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore gnome-shell[1685]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore containerd[1313]: time="2020-05-15T16:15:23.362554120+03:00" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=69402d9f19502efd82ac617dac339cdec3d2cabda5c16812c31791295924a9f3
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore dockerd[2176]: time="2020-05-15T16:15:23.373360792+03:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.527646] docker0: port 1(vetha16701d) entered disabled state
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.527724] veth5b3e62c: renamed from eth0
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore systemd-udevd[13567]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548523.4353] manager: (veth5b3e62c): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/35)
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.584567] docker0: port 1(vetha16701d) entered disabled state
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.601086] device vetha16701d left promiscuous mode
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore kernel: [ 2551.601102] docker0: port 1(vetha16701d) entered disabled state
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548523.4927] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5b3e62c, iface: veth5b3e62c)
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548523.4927] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5b3e62c, iface: veth5b3e62c): no ifupdown configuration found.
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548523.4929] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth5b3e62c, iface: veth5b3e62c)
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548523.4929] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vetha16701d, iface: vetha16701d)
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1589548523.4950] device (vetha16701d): released from master device docker0
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore gnome-shell[2823]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore gnome-shell[2823]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore gnome-shell[1685]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 15 16:15:23 cumucore gnome-shell[1685]: Removing a network device that was not added
```

Also below is my Dokerfile content

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y locales tzdata \
&& apt-get -y install rsyslog \
&& apt-get -y install curl \
&& apt-get install net-tools \
&& apt-get install -y gnupg2 \
&& apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
&& apt-get install -y build-essential

RUN apt-get install libssl1.0.0

RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev libmysqlclient-dev libsctp-dev libevent-dev

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the source from the current directory to the Working Directory inside the container
COPY . .

RUN make FOUR_D=true FIVE_D=true MYSQL=true

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 2123
EXPOSE 38412

# Command to run the executable
CMD ["./BIN_DATA/core"]
```

Docker image creaed after running Dockerfile

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
amfapp              latest              f8d12a091f14        18 hours ago        552MB 
ubuntu              latest              1d622ef86b13        3 weeks ago         73.9MB
```

Comment: if you 'docker container ls -a' and then find the dead container and 'docker logs <container>' do these logs say any different?

Comment: is this docker or kubernetes?

Comment: sudo docker logs a4cea813c641  did not produce any logs. This is docker but am planning to deploy the docker image in Kubernetes. The docker image got created as shown in the post edit but when I deploy it in kubernetes, the pod did not run, the container get created but then crush. I checked the container logs but is no log, also when I describe the pod, it shows that there is a problem with the image, so decided to run the docker image on my local machine. After running it, i saw from /var/logs/syslog the above logs any time i run the image 'sudo docker run amfapp'.